# Strings to Variables containing Strings - Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python and I am trying to make a program. I need to convert a string to a variable which accepts other strings.

```
exec('%s = %d' % ("newVar", 87))
```

This works for integers but is there any format strings like this for strings? Or is there a different method?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I do variable variables in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-do-variable-variables-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dictionary.

```
d = {}
d["newVar"] = 87
d["foo"] = "Hello world!"
print(d["foo"])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're actually looking for is the `%r` specifier, which will work for both integers and strings:

```
>>> exec('%s = %r' % ('var1', 2))
>>> exec('%s = %r' % ('var2', 'foo'))
>>> var1
2
>>> var2
'foo'
```

This uses the `repr`esentation of the parameter, rather than its `s`tring or `d`ecimal version:

```
>>> '%s = %r' % ('var1', 2)
'var1 = 2'
>>> '%s = %r' % ('var2', 'foo')
"var2 = 'foo'"
```

You can read more about the various specifiers in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations).

However, doing *"variable variables"* like this is rarely the appropriate thing to do - as pointed out in [Kevin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32716282/3001761), a dictionary is a much better approach.